# Гринев сказал Пугачеву, что "я тебе служить не стану"

Tags: синтаксис

Гринев сказал Пугачеву, что "я тебе служить не стану".

Будет ли ошибкой такое написание, если взять в кавычки,
вместо следующего:

Гринев сказал Пугачеву, что ему он служить не станет.

Comment: Гринев сказал Пугачеву, что я тебе служить не стану. Здесь очевидная ошибка - смешение прямой и косвенной речи. Если же закавычить ("я тебе служить не стану"), будет это ошибкой? Таких примеров с кавычками в придаточной много. Переделку _Гринев сказал Пугачеву, что ему он служить не станет_ редактор не одобряет, так как ему важно указать на дословность. И прямая речь

Comment: Гринев сказал Пугачеву: "Я тебе служить не стану".

Comment: тоже нежелательна.

Comment: Такое закавычивание придаточной части и, следовательно, смешение прямой и косвенной речи почти в каждой новости. Как быть?

Comment: doom, почему нежелательно? В чем проблема? В предложении Гринев сказал Пугачеву: "Я тебе служить не стану".  нет придаточной части.

Comment: Правильно именно так: Гринев сказал Пугачеву: "Я тебе служить не стану". Это и есть прямая речь.

Comment: В частности, проблема в том, что если уже напечатано в кавычках в придаточной части, то при исправлении на прямую речь непонятно, начинать ее с прописной (если это начало предложения) или с многоточия и строчной (если это не начало предложения). К тому же цитируется, скажем, какой-нибудь президент и точность необходима.

Comment: Или в приведенном примере (школьное сочинение), предположим, надо исправить. Как писать: 1. Гринев сказал Пугачеву: "Я тебе служить не стану". 2. Гринев сказал Пугачеву: "...я тебе служить не стану".

Comment: Но если не знаешь, пропущена ли какая-то часть или нет, то как быть?    Скажем, человек сказал фразу репортеру, последний часть или всю ее закавычил, как школьник в сочинении. Как тогда ее исправить, если кавычки надо все-же привести, чтобы показать, что это не репортером переделанная фраза. Может, так%

Comment: Но если не знаешь, пропущена ли какая-то часть или нет, то как быть?

Comment: Извините, Серж! Не знаю, как получилось, но ваш комментарий удалился после моих попыток ответить на него.

Comment: doom, в своем основном ответе я привел правило оформление прямой речи. Посмотрите, если будет что неясно, пишите - разберемся.

Comment: *К тому же цитируется, скажем, какой-нибудь президент и точность необходима* - doom, если вопрос стоит так, то ничего не остаётся как оформлять прямой речью, дословно, с двоеточиями, тире и кавычками. Тут не разгуляешься.

Comment: Но если ставить вопрос ребром, допустима ли грамматически конструкция в том виде, в каком вы её привели, то подтверждаю свое мнение. Да, допустима. Возражения Сержа строятся на неверном тезисе, что здесь имеет место прямая речь в школьном понимании. А на самом деле там просто слова героя в первозданном виде, использованные в роли грамматической конструкции. Вот у Людмилы возражение хотя бы по сути проблемы, она трактует прямую речь как часть высказывание без замены первого лица на третье и т.п.

Comment: Но это тоже не основание отказывать такой конструкции (как её не назови) в праве быть присоединенной союзом "что". Сложность только одна - на слух плохо воспринимается, кто кому чего сказал и кто кому служить не будет: Гринев, Пугачев или автор самой сентенции. Короче, резюме такое. Для практических надобностей лучше избегать по возможности. Но это стилистика, не грамматика. Правило же оформления на письме прямой речи  (с кавычками, двоеточиями и тире) и косвенной *с заменой грамматического лица при необходимости) как рвз и выдцмано, чтобы избежать подобных коллизий.

Comment: Простите за опечатки и пунктуацию, технические сложности, одним пальцем печатаю.

Comment: Проблема в том, вам и учебник не доказательство. Вы считаете, что правильно именно так, как вам хочется. Вот еще [схема оформления прямой речи](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192)

Comment: Серж, да, мне учебник не доказательство. И что теперь? )))

Comment: А вообще бессодержательный спор. Вы не понимаете одной простой вещи. Я не отрицаю, что написано в учебниках. Но из этого не вытекает, что в исходном оформлении содержится грамматическая ошибка. Все. Разбе6ритесь немножко с логикой. Она у вас на все сто хромает. Вы рассуждаете по Салтыкову-Щедрину "Нет такого закона, чтобы песни петь". К тому же путаете правописание с грамматикой. А я исхожу из понимания самой грамматики. Даже Людмила вынуждена была привести конкретный аргумент, хотя и он меня не устроил. А Вы прете напролом. Типа "Смотри и веруй". А надо еще и понимать.

Answer (score 3):

Такое оформление некорректно, т. к. союз "что" вводит косвенную речь. Перед прямой речью его необходимо убрать.

Дополнение

Смешение прямой и косвенной речи находит свое выражение в том, что придаточное предложение, образующее косвенную речь, сохраняет элементы прямой речи (формы личных местоимений и глаголов), например: ***Автор сгоряча заметил рецензенту, что как же вы можете не замечать того нового, что имеется в книге.***

См.: Розенталь. Д.Э. Справочник по литературной правке и редактированию.

[Оформление прямой речи](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=905.2zG7Civlgka7lphNdxFAuwfvlVJV9vrpb9t_ku1dnKz02I_pZx_kVbsoo4HWzQ0r7h8gyfvNuENPF-e_rqDS-gk3HgaK881utCAIZoA7sjk.799f6546fce7a0296e1e39d06e07502d11069583&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9bb4iM1VPfe4W5x0C0-qwflIRTTifi6VAA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxc1l1cmRySFVrNXdGX2tkM2g5QnZXV1FUdHZlWTNHS3owRkRad2hVZ1pobXhVbEpmLUVaWTF4dFNGQ3pFZXExYUtwX1VnbExLN2ZsWTJOUEJNTU9KVGs2MDFVN1hGZzg2c3BQWmhBYUpwYkJORXhCMVM2Q3BtU3hEWXRILXdIanVn&b64e=2&sign=bd545378cd5b36a615f436ad8dd3aebc&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszk3KfbRmkFJYpv5GmuV-WogafcrsT25mliWAhtXFHBtX2CYHD1k9vyzvpUV6ZNILXnlo8GUag-y5o3lAkkrGYc90YSxLerQS7d2oNPoXYGGDGfaWlzGNsw-8M4sEBdjcwM6r97RGEFhf9oZ52jEIkUepb3NT39HXjzA&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpVBUyA8nmgRG9LVuSbjgZ0DrKaVDAACe6DckIMgicCELzJM9CbIlgO2ubwqHv4lTTsEHKhS8Z3ZbvIXPTdZ8sy-OWUO47hempWu4PzYw24WPm1q8wTNiMD6anQ3EneqiWl5s_0Dm2OTihVzvlGtcIMtGw7I8YQ5CLDlAbwBEsxjO5rxhVt58bx1_FWhWwV0GChfhKkgaEuhrjJi36KxCNDq20XyX8qrKHQo8y2bPIZfaOEuzSPKaNNGzONUDC4v5N&l10n=ru&cts=1450361740691&mc=4.3940654468927605)

Comment: Серж, а Вы вообще понимаете, что в Вашем примере нет кавычек? Как и во всех примерах ошибок подобного рода из Розенталя и других источников? Или вам уже все равно?

Comment: А без спора ответить не можете? Интересное кино))).

Comment: *А вы встречали когда-нибудь обсуждаемый нами спорный пример?* - в это еще зачем? Я, скажем, папуаса никогда не встречал. Что теперь, папуасы запрещены? Суть же не в том, кто когда встречал, а в грамматике. Вы признали, что цитата - прячая речь. Следовательно, в цитате изменять лицо не требуется. А про то, что цитатату **нельзя** присоединять с помощью что - это уже не пример, это по-Вашему запрет некий, и его надо найти в явном виде, убедить окружающих, что он существует. А примеры, что такое возможно, я приводил.

Comment: *Я ничего не признавал.* - а это кто писал? - *Цитаты являются разновидностью прямой речи* Или  Вы теперь будете говорить,  что не согласны с тем процитировали?

Comment: *Но это не значит, что это одно и то же.Цитату как раз можно присоединять с помощью "что'', в правилах это оговорено.* - Все больше мне ничего от Вас и не требуется. Вот я (ну или автор вопроса) и присоединил ***цитату***. А то, что кому-то это не понравилось, - это его дело. К грамматике не имеет никакого отношения. Остальное - ффтопку. Раз не встречали прямого указания, что нельзя, то очевидно, что можно. Это нормальная постановка вопроса. А рассуждения "раз не встречали то очевидно, что нельзя" - это вы будете в суде доказывать, когда Вас за инсинуации  туда попросят.

Comment: *"Нет такого закона чтобы песни петь"* (с)Михаил Евграфович. Не уподобляйтесь его герою.

Comment: Мне уже никогда не придется сдавать экзамены по родному языку. Я слишком стар для этого. ))) А лет пятнадцать назад мне довелось косвенно поучаствовать в рассмотрении апелляций. Но жто никакого отношения к существу вопроса не имеет.

Comment: behemothus, я удалил свои комментарии, а то замечание приходит от администрации.

Comment: Мне не приходит. И почему я должен удалять? Кстати, я не жаловался, если что.

Comment: Я имею в виду просят перенести комментария в чат.Вы не видели разве?

Comment: Ну пускай просят. ))) Это не Администрация а движок форумный. Помнится, вы категорически отвергали саму идею общаться в чате. Даже когда в этом был смысл. А сейчас-то что? У меня все по делу.

Answer (score 1):

Это грубая грамматическая ошибка: смешение прямой (от 1 лица) и косвенной (от 3 лица) речи. Если прямая речь, то в кавычках и только ***я***, если косвенная, то только ***он*** и в виде придаточного предложения с союзом *что, как* и т.д.

Comment: А если цитата? Людмила от Вас странно слышать. Автор вообще не уточняет, что его интересует прямая ли тут речь.

Comment: Да и вообще дело не в этом. Где сказано, что придаточное присоединенное с помощью "что" не может содержать авторских слов в кавычках? Некогда искать, а то бы я вам примеров кучу нашел.

Comment: *Еще в сентябре 1917 г. в работе «Грозящая катастрофа и как с ней бороться» Ленин писал, что «без смертной казни по отношению к эксплуататорам ...»* https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=i5tyVpuHKKv6ygO91Y_wAg - и таких примеров миллион.

Comment: Вы не усмотрели здесь главного - присутствия местоимения Я вместо ОН: Гринев сказал Пугачеву, что "я тебе служить не стану", а надо "что он не станет". В задании №7 ЕГЭ именно такие ошибки и приводятся - на смешение прямой и косвенной речи, да Вы и сами усмотрели "неестественное построение фразы", т.е. грамматическую ошибку

Comment: Ну, Людмила, это несерьезно. Вы причину со следствием смешиваете. Потому и кавычки убирают при непрямой речи, что надо менять лицо местоимения. А здесь они не убраны. Потому и нет замены местоимения. А что так нельзя, нигде не сказано. Это первое. Я усмотрел стилистическую неряшливость, при полной грамматической правильности. Это второе. Собственно, дальше и не хочется спорить. А если бы у Ленина в итате там дальше местоимение прорезалось? Ну не у Ленина, у Чехова, скажем?! Что, сразу грамматика нарушается?

Comment: Грамматика нарушена не из-за применения кавычек. Кавычки говорят о том, что это цитата, а цитаты могут быть оформлены или в виде самостоятельного предложения, или как прямая речь(от первого лица после двоеточия или перед тире), или как косвенная речь(от 3 лица) в виде  придаточного предложения.Здесь оформлено как сложноподчинённое предложение, следовательно, косвенная речь, т.е. 1 лицо недопустимо и у Чехова никак "не прорежется".

Comment: Правильно:«Я знаю в жизни только два действительных несчастья: угрызение совести и болезнь», — говорит князь Андрей Пьеру.Князь Андрей говорит Пьеру, что знает в жизни «только два действительных несчастья: угрызение совести и болезнь». А вот фраза с ошибкой: Князь Андрей говорит Пьеру, что " я знаю в жизни  только два действительных несчастья: угрызение совести и болезнь". И это классическая грамматическая ошибка на смешение прямой и косвенной речи.

Comment: Людмила, но это декларация. Вы называете ошибкой то, что вам не нравится. А объяснить, какое правило нарушает такое построение фразы? Нигде не сказано, что в в точных, закавыченных цитатах надо менять Я на он и т.п. Точно также нигде не сказано, что в цитату нельзя включать в текст с помощью союза что. Так что - не принимается. Грамматической ошибки нет.

Comment: *Кавычки говорят о том, что это цитата...* - Кавычки эито индикатор того, что фраза приведена дословно, "добуквенно",  я бы даже сказал. Я же вам привел пример массового использования цитаты, присоединенной с помощью "что" и кавычек. Вы как классифицируете этот случай? Если скажете, что и это ошибка, то она слишком массовая, не верю. На самостоятельное предложение не тянет. Остается *прямая речь". А в прямой речи лицо говорящего не меняется.

Comment: Ну, уж это не смешно, Вы просто упрямничаете. Вы что, в школе не учили правила оформления цитат - я Вам их привела: только прямая речь ИЛИ косвенная, а здесь совмещение - это ошибка. Потому что местоимение "Я" передаёт ТОЛЬКО речь говорящего или пишущего, ты -образ собеседника, а если я пишу о Пугачёве и Гринёве, они для меня -ОНИ, а не "Я"

Comment: Людмила, я понимаю, что такая прямая и косвенная речь. Я не понимаю, с чего ты взяли что  здесь имеет место какое-то "смешение". Здесь цитата. Если угодно, называйте её прямой речью. Но тогда признайте, что прямая речь может присоединяться с помощью "что". И то, что ни в цитате, ни в прямой речи и не требуется  замены лица говорящего. А повторять бесконечно одно и то же заклинание про "смещение" - это да, смешно. Я уже ответил, что здесь нет смешения.

Comment: Людмила, я все-таки прошу ответить. *Еще в сентябре 1917 г. в работе «Грозящая катастрофа и как с ней бороться» Ленин писал, что «без смертной казни по отношению к эксплуататорам ...»*  - Здесь есть ошибка или нет? Именно здесь, в этой фразе. Если есть, то где это сказано. Если ошибки нет,  то что это прямая речь или косвенная? Или все-таки смешение?

Comment: В этой фразе нет ошибки, потому что нет местоимений  1 лица, Ленин говорит от 3 лица. Цитата оформлена в виде предложения с косвенной речью, т.е. сложноподчинённого с союзом ЧТО, но когда цитата оформляется как косвенная речь, а используется местоимение 1 лица "Я", возможное только в прямой речи, ЭТО ОШИБКА, а Вы её видеть не желаете. Вот посмотрите предложение: Валерий сказал, что "я его видеть не желаю". Я-это говорящий, а речь идёт о том, что ВАЛЕРИЙ кого-то видеть не желает.Должно быть:Валерий сказал, что "ОН его видеть не желаЕТ".

Comment: И это называется смешением прямой и косвенной речи, т.е. смешением передачи чужой речи от 1 и от 3 лица, когда лица перепутываются. Это классическая грамматическая ошибка в ученических сочинениях.

Comment: *"В этой фразе нет ошибки, потому что нет местоимений 1 лица"* - Людмила, но вот это уже действительно смешно. Вы говорите, что ошибки нет, потому что нет 1-го лица. И при этом прекрасно знаете, что при прямом цитировании (в кавычках), лицо не меняется. Давайте по порядку. У Ленина - цитата?  Прямая речь? Если да, то почему в прямой речи появление 1-го лица запрещено?  Логику давайте. Все разговоры, предполагающие, что я не знаю,того что в школе проходят (ну по этой теме), давайте оставим. Я прекрасно знаю, что детей так учат, на догматических положениях. Но я этого не приемлю.

Comment: Я, кстати, с первого класса (не утрирую) за это двойки получал, что тыкал носом учителку в некорректность объяснений. Типа не принимал некорректные объяснения. Начиная с того, что умышленно "проверял" гласную в "сидел" словом "сел". Пока не добился внятного объяснения о корневом чередовании. Так и тут. Если сказано, что это цитата, т.е. прямая речь, то  или давайте четкую формулировку, что в ***цитате*** запрещено использовать первое лицо именно ***по грамматике*** (ну или как вы там это понимаете), или признавайте, что тут что-то не так с формулировками.

Comment: *Цитата оформлена в виде предложения с косвенной речью, т.е. сложноподчинённого с союзом ЧТО, но когда цитата оформляется как косвенная речь, а используется местоимение 1 лица "Я", возможное только в прямой речи, ЭТО ОШИБКА, а Вы её видеть не желаете.* - вот покажите мне, что это противоречит общей грамматике. Что для цитат есть отдельное правило, по которому с помощью "что" нельзя цеплять лирические цитаты. Не на внушении, а в серьезном академическом учебнике грамматики. Если покажете именно такую формулировку, или ей эквивалентную, соглашусь сразу. Я такого не видел.

Answer (score 0):

Несколько неестественное построение фразы, но в целом грамматически все верно. 
А что смущает-то?  Союз "что", вопреки Сержу, подчиняет придаточное, а уж как там это придаточное должно быть построено, с прямой речью или косвенной, цитатой или еще чем-либо, нигде не сказано.

Так что ошибка тут если и есть, то только стилистическая, без "что" и без запятой проще и логичнее выразить мысль. Но если автор очень настаивает именно на таком построении фразы (по контексту, например), то ему виднее, грамматика не запрещает.

//----------------------------

Я вынужден повторить, почему я не согласен, ни с Сержем (ну тут просто и спорить не с чем), ни даже с Людмилой. Фокус очень простой. Оба говорят о наличии какого-то смешения прямой и косвенной речи, не доказав (ни себе, ни другим) наличия этого смешения.

Я же рассуждаю очень просто.

Берем абсолютно правильный пунтркационно и грамматически оформленный пример текста пример текста:

> Еще в сентябре 1917 г. в работе «Грозящая катастрофа и как с ней бороться» Ленин писал, что «без смертной казни по отношению к эксплуататорам ...»

Здесь есть "что" и есть цитата. Смешения нет. При этом нигде не сказано (да и не может быть сказано), что запрещено цитировать таким или любым другим способом текст написанный от первого лица или что при прямом цитировании требуется или хотя бы допустимо менять грамматическое лицо - тогда цитирование перестает быть цитированием.

Другими словами, я не вижу здесь ни прямой речи, ни косвенной - в том понимании, о котором говорит Людмила. Это прямая цитата. Поэтому ни о каком смешении не может идти речь.

Вот как только мне объяснят, где в моих рассуждениях ошибка, я готов буду согласиться. "Объяснить" это не значит показать очередной источник, где говорится о смешении прямой и косвенной речи. Объяснить - это значит найти конкретную ошибку у меня в логике или в исходной позиции. Логике я верю несравнимо больше указания на источники, где разбираются случаи истинного смешения (они, поверьте, мне хорошо известны).

Comment: Найдите мне учебник, где написано, что такое посторение фразы **нарушает грамматику**. Есть хорошая русская пословица "На сарае тоже написано, а там дрова лежат". *А когда человек начинает ссылаться на все учебники, хочется уточнить,  что  "он хоть один читал".*

Comment: Теоретический и практический материал по теме «Синтаксические нормы» в пособии Балашовой Л.В., Дементьева В.В. «Русский язык и культура общения»[Некоторые особенности употребления сложных предложений, прямой и косвенной речи](http://www.licey.net/russian/culture/3_7)

Comment: Правило сформулировано во всех учебниках по стилистике со времен Розенталя: "Смешение прямой и косвенной речи находит свое выражение в том, что придаточное предложение, образующее косвенную речь, сохраняет элементы прямой речи (формы личных местоимений и глаголов)". Например: Автор заметил, что как же вы можете не видеть этого (Розенталь. Справочник по правописанию, раздел "Ошибки в сложных предложениях").

Comment: Кавычки ничего не меняют. В случае кавычек мы имеем дело не с классической прямой речью, а с прямой речью или цитатой, которые стали членом предложения, в данном случае - частью придаточного предложения, которое образует косвенную речь и не может содержать первого лица, но может содержать все остальные дословные выдержки.

Comment: Вы не учитываете особенность косвенной речи: она может содержать фрагменты дословного высказывания (то есть закавыченные фрагменты), но не может содержать формы личных местоимений и глаголов. То есть не все дословные фрагменты могут быть частью придаточного предложения. Эти вопросы рассматриваются в работах, посвященных переходу прямой речи в косвенную. А вообще то, с чем вы спорите, - это аксиома. Не все правила сформулированы подробно, иногда нужен системный подход.

Comment: *Вы не учитываете особенность косвенной речи* - это Вам кажется. Я вообще не считаю, что данный случай надо рассматривать как к5освенную речь.  Это цитата.  А вот Вы вслед за Сержем делаете одну и ту же логическую ошибку. Ставите свое понимания правил пунктуационного оформления выше грамматики. оформления . Иди покажите мне, что слова в кавычках кто-то из серьезных авторов квалифицирует как косвенную речь.

Comment: И не надо мне про аксиомы. Я по образованию и по жизни - математик.)))  Меня этими словами не запугаешь. Формулировку давайте своей "аксимы".

Comment: Дискуссия не имеет смысла. Я дам вам ссылки на авторов, а вы скажете, что они  "несерьезные", или "не математики", или пытаются вас "запугать". Останемся каждый при своем мнении.

Comment: *Дискуссия не имеет смысла* - конечно, если вы её не умеете вести. Если вы заранее знаете, что я скажу - ну какая тут может быть дискуссия? Но причина не в том, конечно. Дискуссия на уровне "мнений" бессодержательна. Логикой надо оперировать. И понимать, что именно вам возражают. Вы же просто проигнорировали основной мой тезис. О том, что ***здесь нет косвенной речи***. Вот в чем фокус-то. Если будут ссылки, доказывающие обратное, то я, разумеется, не скажу иное.